# Explode a string to an array

Tags: php, regex, split, explode

Probably easy to do but I can't seem to generate the correct regex.

Say I have this string

```
$string = '<h2>Header 1</h2><p>ahs da sdka dshk asd haks</p><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/" width="100" height="100" alt="Alt" /><h2>Header 2</h2><p>asdkhas daksdha kd ahs</p><em>Lame</em><p>trhkbasd akhsd ka dkhas</p><h2>Header 3</h2><p>ajdas ahkds hakd</p>';
```

And I need it like this

```
$array[0] = '<h2>Header 1</h2><p>ahs da sdka dshk asd haks</p><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/" width="100" height="100" alt="Alt" />';
$array[1] = '<h2>Header 2</h2><p>asdkhas daksdha kd ahs</p><em>Lame</em><p>trhkbasd akhsd ka dkhas</p>';
$array[2] = '<h2>Header 3</h2><p>ajdas ahkds hakd</p>';
```

...and so on if my string contains more of those H2 blocks.

So, the split-point is at H2 and it needs to keep the HTML-tags. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_split()` with a positive lookahead for the opening tag:

```
print_r(preg_split('/(?=<h2>)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

The positive lookahead simply tells the regex parser to split text surrounding `<h2>`, but not eliminate the tag. If you split by `/<h2>/`, the tag disappears, just like if you split with `explode()`.

Comment: This did the trick. And I was on PHP 5.3.0> so no split() for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = split('(?=<h2>)', $string);
```

or

```
$result = preg_split('/(?=<h2>)/', $string);
```

Comment: `split()` is deprecated in favor of `preg_split()`. But this is still a valid answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<h2>Header 1</h2><p>ahs da sdka dshk asd haks</p><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/" width="100" height="100" alt="Alt" /><h2>Header 2</h2><p>asdkhas daksdha kd ahs</p><em>Lame</em><p>trhkbasd akhsd ka dkhas</p><h2>Header 3</h2><p>ajdas ahkds hakd</p>';

$matches    = split('<h2>', $string);

print_r($matches);
```

This is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 though.